# bzr shelve some files that are being worked on

Tags: bazaar

Lets say I have 6 files that I'm working on and I only want to shelve 3 of the 6

1. Is this correct  `bzr shelve file1.txt file2.txt file5.txt -m "this is the thing"`
2. How do I unshelve it later?
3. How do I delete the shelve if I do not need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct `bzr shelve file1.txt file2.txt file5.txt -m "this is the thing"`

Yes, that's correct. It will shelve the changes to the specified files and directories only. Furthermore:

- If there are no changes in those, it will do nothing, just tell you *No changes to shelve.*
- To skip the interactive questions for every change in those files, the `--all` flag is convenient, for example: `bzr shelve file1.txt file2.txt file5.txt -m "this is the thing" --all`

> How do I unshelve it later?

Find the id of the shelf with `bzr shelve --list`. Then unshelve with `bzr unshelve THE_ID`. Btw, if you don't specify an id, then `bzr unshelve` will unshelve the most recent shelf.

> How do I delete the shelve if I do not need it?

Using the `--delete-only` flag of `bzr unshelve`, for example:

```
bzr unshelve --delete-only THE_ID
```